# Flash still scales elements even if NO_SCALE is set

Tags: flash, actionscript, resize, scale

im trying to set up a simple form where you can type a pin and submit it to switch to another movieclip. Im using Flash CS5 and ActionScript 3. I have some MovieClips which get resized on a RESIZE Event. The movieclips get perfectly resized to the stages size so they fill it out.

The problem i have is the scaling.

To avoid scaling everything i used the following two lines.

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

I see the stage is aligned to the top left. But still if i resize my browser or even the flash preview (CTRL+Enter in Adobe Flash) all elements like the textbox, the label and the button are resized proportionally.

I just want to keep the width/height of these elemenst, no matter what size the stage has.
So if someone resizes his browser making the stage a bigger player, it is like the elements now have more space to use, but instead the space they have is the same because everything is stretched. So even if have the SWF being shown in my Full-HD view, still the elements have only something like 550x400 pixel in total because thats the default size of my flash document based on the properties settings.

Can anybody help solving this?
Because i want to load images on the next screen. So if the browsers width is 1000 pixel i would get something like 10 images in a row. But if the browser resizes to 2000 pixels because the user just clicked on the "Maximize" button for the browser window, then obviously my flash document should print 20 images in a row as there are now another 1000 pixels of space. You know what i mean?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Just to be clearer. I started a new flash project trying to reproduce this problem only to be sure that its not because of bad code.

I created a new FLA project. Added a simple rectangle, converted it into MovieClip and named its instance "mc". then i created a second layer for the actionscript part. I added the following code:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.text.*;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener);

function resizeListener (e:Event):void {
  mc.width = stage.stageWidth;
  mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
  mc.x = 0;
  mc.y = 0;
}

var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.text = "This is my new text...";
mc.addChild( myText);
```

Thats it. The resizing works fine, this is what i want as the movieclip "mc" will act as page so i will have more movieclips resized to stage size to switch between them by using visible property.
But still the text appearing on the very top left in the movieclip (so in the stage) is scaled everytime i resize the window. Why?

Comment: Are you sure this code is executed and stage is not null? Could you try to recheck with trace statement.

Comment: I use the Adobe Flash IDE. It wont run if it doesnt compile. I used trace to print some stage properties. NO_SCALE and TOP_LEFT are set on runtime. Thats why im confused. Everything looks right, but its still stretching.

Comment: When you set mc.width, you are inadvertently scaling the mc clip, because width is tied to scaleX and height is tied to scaleY.  The NO_SCALE option applies only the stage, not individual movie clips, which you can always scale.  If you don't want "width" to scale your clip, then you need to override the default implementation of width and height, and instead of setting super.width or super.height, you have to store the new values in private variables and have the property setters call your own layout code, which must adjust the *positions* of *all* child objects to fit the new width & height.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution. But iam NOT happy with this.

I need to add an event listener to the parent movieClip. Everytime the function gets called i need to call these 2 lines FOR EACH child element in the MovieClip.

```
myText.scaleX = 1 / mc.scaleX;
myText.scaleY = 1 / mc.scaleY;
```

As Flash always scales EVERYTHING (for whatever reason) i need to rescale the child elements accordingly. So if the parent MovieClip resize to double size (so scale multiplys by 2), then all child elements need to have scale property set to 0.5 ( so half sized).
That keeps child elements same size.

To be honest this is a bad solution. That means i need to updated ALL child elements everytime the parent MovieClip resizes.

Please dont tell me that this is the only solution.... :-(

Comment: Wait... why are you talking about scaling the parent element?  Of course if you scale the parent element, all the children get scaled with it.  The NO_SCALE option prevents the STAGE from being scaled, not individual display objects.

Comment: In Flash, width and scale are linked.  If you want to be able to resize an object without scaling it, then you need to override the width and height properties, and you need to add layout routines to adjust the position of child display objects like TextFields and other controls to account for the new width.  Of course you'd have to update all the child controls.

Comment: The default implementation of width property "function get width" will return a value corresponding to the size of the content currently in the clip, including stroke widths (i.e. what you'd get from calling getBounds as opposed to getRect).  When you change the width property, it simultaneously changes the scale relative to the content's actual width.  If your clip is originally 100px wide, and you change the width to 200px, then you'll notice that scaleX becomes 2.  So the original width is actually always (width / scaleX), because width and scale always change together.